# byte array assignment

Tags: c++

```
byte test[4];
memset(test,0x00,4);

test[]={0xb4,0xaf,0x98,0x1a};
```

the above code is giving me an error expected primary-expression before ']' token.
can anyone tell me whats wrong with this type of assignment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What Ben and Chris are saying is.

```
byte test[4]={0xb4,0xaf,0x98,0x1a};
```

If you want to do it at run time, you can use memcpy to do the job.

```
byte startState[4]={0xb4,0xaf,0x98,0x1a};
byte test[4];

memcpy(test, startState, sizeof(test));
```

Comment: basically i have like 5 byte arrays that i wanted to selectively use based on some initial data that i parse. So, i was thinking about setting up an array and then putting values in it which would never change i guess i would put const on it as well since it will never change.

Answer (score 17):

Arrays cannot be assigned. You can only **initialize** them with the braces.

The closest you can get, if you want to "assign" it later, is declaring another array and copying that:

```
const int array_size = 4;
char a[array_size] = {};  //or {0} in C.
char b[array_size] = {0xb4,0xaf,0x98,0x1a};
std::copy(b, b + array_size, a);
```

or using the array class from std::tr1 or boost:

```
#include <tr1/array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::tr1::array<char, 4> a = {};

    std::tr1::array<char, 4> b = {0xb4,0xaf,0x98,0x1a};    
    a = b; //those are assignable

    for (unsigned i = 0; i != a.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: if i assign values using copy will there be scoping issues if i use it in the confines of an if statement? what i want to do is use one byte array in all the functions but have 4 other byte inputs. when i know which one i want to use i then copy to the generic byte array (i was going to put this int he if statement.)

Comment: You will be *copying* the byte values, so no problem if the source array has a smaller scope.

Comment: if i wanted to confirm the copy went through fine is there a way to print out the values of this  byte array?? how can i tell if the copy passed or not with proper values?

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [@Chris Lutz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240405/byte-array-assigment/2240431#2240431)'s correct answer:

```
byte test[]={0xb4,0xaf,0x98,0x1a};
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly specify the array size in this case unless you want the array length to be larger than the number of elements between the brackets.

This only works if you're initializing the array when it is declared.  Otherwise you'll have to initialize each array element explicitly using your favorite technique (loop, STL algorithm, etc).

Comment: Also note that you can auto-determine the array size with: `size_t numTestElems = sizeof(test) / sizeof(byte);`

Comment: @Mike - Or, since this is C++, `template <class T, size_t N> size_t array_size(T (&n)[N]) { return N; }` used as `size_t numTestElems = array_size(test);`

Comment: @Mike: I'd go with sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]).  That way you don't have to worry about potential type mix-ups.

Comment: @Chris:  I've never seen that before (sadly :)).  Very nice!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [@UncleBens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240405/byte-array-assigment/2240414#2240414)'s correct answer, I want to note that this:

```
byte test[4];
memset(test,0x00,4);
```

Can be shortened to:

```
byte test[4] = { 0 };
```

This is the initialization syntax that you're trying to use. The language will fill up un-assigned spaces with 0, so you don't have to write `{ 0, 0, 0, 0 }` (and so that, if your array length changes later, you don't have to add more).

Comment: Which can be further shortened to byte test[4] = {};, but I do prefer the {0} as well.

Comment: @John - It can, but only in C++. In C (which is what I do predominantly) you have to have at least one value.

Comment: `byte test[4] = { 0 };` always made me think that what was in the braces was getting assigned to all the elements (like in one of C++'s `std::vector` constructors).

Comment: @Mike: Nope, you are just specifying the first element.  All the remaining elements will be value-initialized, which in this case means set to 0.