# string <-> byte[] conversions

Tags: c++, arrays, string, byte, libcrafter

I'm implementing a system that uses `libcrafter` and `crypto++` to transmit specific frames on the network. But the problem I'm stuck with isn't at this level at all.

It's about conversion between types used in these libraries.

---

### 1) At the emission (solved)

I'm trying to convert the `Crafter::byte array` to a  `std::string`, in order to put this message into a network frame (as an *initialization vector* for an AES encryption/decryption).

Moreover, the `iv` must be zeroed, and I can't initialize it properly (despite the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240405/byte-array-assignment) or [there](http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/initialize-byte-array-592458.html)).

**EDIT** : to initialize it to 00, I had to do it **in hexadecimal** : 0x30. And to convert it to a `std::string` I had to provide the length ie ivLen2 (thanks for the answers).

Here's what I do :

```
const int ivLen2 = 2;
std::string encrypted_message("whatever");

Crafter::byte iv[ivLen2]={0x30, 0x30}; // crypto salt of 2 bytes at 0.

std::string ivStr( reinterpret_cast< char const* >(iv), ivLen2 ) ;

string mess2send = ivStr + encrypted_message;
```

And if I display them, with this :

```
cout<<"iv[0] : "<<iv[0]<<endl;            // display 0
cout<<"mess2send : "<<mess2send<<endl;    // display 00whatever
```

*Why don't I simply create a zeroed string and send it ?* In order to have generic functions, and a re-usable code.

---

### 2) At the reception (pending)

Without surprises I have to do the opposite. I get a `iv` and the `message` concatenated within a `vector<byte>* payload`, and I have to extract the iv as a `byte array`, and the `message` within a string.

The `message` isn't actually the problem, given that `std::string` is close to `vector`.

Here's what I tempt to retrieve the `iv` :

```
Crafter::byte iv[ ivLen2 ];
for (int i = 0; i < ivLen2; i++)
{
    iv[i] = (byte)payload->at(i);
}
std::string iv_rcv( reinterpret_cast< char const* >(iv) ) ;
```

And to display them, I do (in the same loop) :

```
cout<<iv[i];
```

But it gives me a non-ASCII character.

I've also tried this (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/505047/3494633) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/347959/3494633) answers) :

```
Crafter::byte* iv;

std::string iv_rcv( payload->begin(), payload->begin()+ivLen2 ) ;
iv = (byte*)iv_rcv.c_str();
```

But it doesn't give me the *supposed* initialized values...

Does anybody have a clue ? Is my code wrong ?

Comment: Strings have length. What is the length of this string `reinterpret_cast< char const* >(iv)`? Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uint8_t can't be printed with cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout/19562163#19562163). At least regarding the 1st part.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will work:

```
const int ivLen2 = 2;
std::string encrypted_message("whatever");

Crafter::byte iv[ivLen2]={0x00, 0x00}; // crypto salt of 2 bytes

std::string ivStr( reinterpret_cast< char const* >(iv) ) ;
```

How does the `std::string` know how much data to copy from the `iv` pointer?

You have to use a constructor that takes the *length* of the data like:

```
std::string ivStr( reinterpret_cast< char const* >(iv), ivLen2 ) ;
```

The *pointer only* constructor is for specifically encoded strings that are terminated by a *null character*. Unless you are using one of those you must pass the length.

Try this:

```
const int ivLen2 = 2;
std::string encrypted_message("whatever");

Crafter::byte iv[ivLen2]={0x00, 0x00}; // crypto salt of 2 bytes

std::string ivStr( reinterpret_cast< char const* >(iv), ivLen2 ) ;

std::string mess2send = ivStr + encrypted_message;

std::cout << (int)mess2send[0] << (int)mess2send[1] << mess2send.substr(2) << '\n';
```

Comment: OK, thanks! :) But I still have the problem of the initialization. It doesn't gives me `00`, even if a convert it in hex...

Comment: @EisenHeim `std::cout` will not show you `00` because what you put in there was two character codes with value `0`, not two character codes with values that are represented by the letter `'0'`.

Comment: @EisenHeim Try this: `std::cout << (int)mess2send[0] << (int)mess2send[1] << mess2send.substr(2) << '\n';`

Comment: @Ga Lik - `error: ‘std::string’ has no member named ‘substring’`

Comment: @EisenHeim my error I have edited it to fix bug and use your string name

Comment: It displays me `10whatever` ! :) Could `10` be the values of the initialized `iv` ?

Comment: @EisenHeim I don't know why that's happening for you. The code I posted at the end of my answer produces this: `00whatever
`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the new edit. Yeah, now it's working ! I think I'll look at the reception on monday. Thanks and have a nice WE !